# Solve heat balance equations in discrete time

Tags: matlab, equation, heat

I want to solve heat balance in discrete time within 2 or 3 offices using system of differential equations in Matlab. Therefore, I set up following equations:

```
C1*(dT1/dt)=U12*A1*(T1(t)-T2(t))+U13*A2*(T1(t)-T3(t))+H1(t);
C2*(dT2/dt)=U21*A1*(T1(t)-T2(t))+U23*A2*(T2(t)-T3(t))+H2(t)
```

**C,U,A** are parameters and **T3(t),H1(t) and H2(t)** are functions which vary over time. I want to calculate T1 and T2 in discrete time. Beside that, I want to involve thermostat control in equations.

I already tried to solve this but only with one equation and I obtained linear graph. Could somebody give me some instructions or suggestions how I need to set up this and solve it? I really appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [finite difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) for the derivatives.

```
dT/dt =~ (T(n) - T(n-1))/(dt)
```

Where `T(n)` is the temperature at time step `n` and `dt` is the time between samples.

```
C1*((T1(n) - T1(n-1))/dt)=U12*A1*(T1(n)-T2(n))+U13*A2*(T1(n)-T3(n))+H1(n)
C2*((T2(n) - T2(n-1))/dt)=U21*A1*(T1(n)-T2(n))+U23*A2*(T2(n)-T3(n))+H2(n)
```

Now, just solve the system of equations for `T1(n)` and `T2(n)`.  I use [sympy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) for simple, but tedious algebra like this.  Then just initialize all your parameters and simulate the equations for `N` steps like so:

```
function [T1,T2] = simHeatEqns(N)
  dt = ..
  U12 = ..
  .
  .
  .
  % simulate for N steps
  for n=2:N
    T1(n) = (A1*A2*T3(n)*U12*U23*dt^2 - A1*A2*T3(n)*U13*U21*dt^2 + A1*C1*T1(n-1)*U21*dt - A1*C2*T2(n-1)*U12*dt + A1*H1n*U21*dt^2 - A1*H2n*U12*dt^2 + A2^2*T3(n)*U13*U23*dt^2 - A2*C1*T1(n-1)*U23*dt - A2*C2*T3(n)*U13*dt - A2*H1n*U23*dt^2 + C1*C2*T1(n-1) + C2*H1n*dt)/(A1*A2*U12*U23*dt^2 - A1*A2*U13*U21*dt^2 + A1*C1*U21*dt - A1*C2*U12*dt + A2^2*U13*U23*dt^2 - A2*C1*U23*dt - A2*C2*U13*dt + C1*C2)
    T2(n) = (A1*U21*(-A2*T3(n)*U13*dt + C1*T1(n-1) + H1n*dt)/(A1*U12*dt + A2*U13*dt - C1) - (-A2*T3(n)*U23*dt + C2*T2(n-1) + H2n*dt)/dt)/(A1^2*U12*U21*dt/(A1*U12*dt + A2*U13*dt - C1) + (-A1*U21*dt + A2*U23*dt - C2)/dt)
  end
end
```

Comment: @nikola23, were you looking for something more?

Comment: Hi,I defined procedure and parameters here:
dt=0.1;
n = 168/dt;
params...
Then, I copied these equation in the editor as you recommended. Is that correct or I have to add something else? It's reported some error. 
Additionaly, I want to apply thermostat setting. Could I do that with if loop? 
I really need some help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi! I am really shortage of time and I need to solve this very quick because also certain analysis is required.
Could you give more details about this? I have already written something in previous post.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi,
I wrote some procedure for solving system of difference equation but it reports some error. Could you take a look is it correct?
Thanks!
function [T1,T2] = simHeatEqns(n)
T1(1)=15;
T2(1)=13;
t = 0;
t_final = 168;
dt = 0.5;
n = 168/delta_t;
U12 = 3;
U21 = 3;
U13 = 2;
U23 = 2;
A1 = 7.8;
A2 = 26.8;
C1 = 1000*10^4;
C2 = 1000*10^4;
H1(1) = 1000;
H2(1) = 0;
T3(1) = 5;

for i = 2:n
    C1*((T1(n) - T1(n-1))/dt)=U12*A1*(T1(n)-T2(n))+U13*A2*(T1(n)-T3(n))+H1(n);
    C2*((T2(n) - T2(n-1))/dt)=U21*A1*(T1(n)-T2(n))+U23*A2*(T2(n)-T3(n))+H2(n);

Comment: And end of the procdure

T1(i+1) = T1(i)+delta_t*dT1dt;
    T2(i+1) = T2(i)+delta_t*dT2dt;
    t(i+1) = t(i) + delta_t;
end
plot(t,T1,T2);
end

Comment: Sorry, I really can't help much more.  Hope your project turns out well!

Comment: Hi,
I suppose that you are busy but I finally solved the system. Another thing that I wan to apply here is heater control. If I have T1 and T2, I define this function:
function [on,off] = heater(T1,T2)
on = true;
off = else;
if(T1>= 18 && T1<=20)
heater on = true;
else if (T2>=18 && T2<= 20)
heater on = 1;
else 
heater off = 1;
end.

Could you check is it correct and should I make some corrections? Thanks a lot in advance!